# stable_baseline3 graphical output in docker

Tags: python, docker, gpu, display

I'm currently running into the following challenge.

I have a docker container running Python 3.9. I linked my GPU to this container (Nvidia GTX1070).
When I run Nvidia-smi inside the container it shows the graphics card, so I'm assuming that the link is there.

I'm interacting with this container using Visual studio code (Remote Explorer).
I installed the stable_baselines3[extra] package. And I’m able to import and use it (no issues there)

I'm following a tutorial, so it is not my code, I'm able to run this and it does give me the appropriate output, but the only thing that is not working is the following line: env.redner(), in the tutorial this gives graphical output in a window. But that doesn't happen on my setup

Is there anyone that can help me with this challenge?

Kind regards

Alex

```
import os
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import ppo
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy


#Load the enviroment
enviroment_name = 'CartPole-v0'
env = gym.make(enviroment_name)



episodes = 5000
for episode in range(1,episodes+1):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0

    while not done:
        env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        n_state, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        score += reward
    print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
env.close()
```

As stated above I tried to hook up my GPU to the container and I checked every capabilities

```
--gpus 'device=0,"capabilities=compute,graphics,utility,video,display,compat32"'
```